# Curl php don't save cookie

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I need your help.
When I open this page in browser https://www.g2a.com/toolbar/toolbar?isAjax=ajax
I open inspector and between tags  i find key:123456
And if I reload page, the key:is kept 123456

But when i used curl, I always get different keys -123478, 84561a...

I need to simulate browser using php and curl

my code

```
$loginurl = 'https://www.g2a.com/toolbar/toolbar?isAjax=ajax';
$useragent = "Fake Mozilla 5.0 ";
$cookie_jar = tempnam("tmp", "g2a");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_jar);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie_jar);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$redir = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
curl_close($ch);


echo $result;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look in the $cookie_jar file to see if anything actually got saved (or if the file was even created?)

Comment: files are created and information wrote